# Change a percentage of dataframe column values according to the value of another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, conditional-statements

I have a dataframe similar to the one below, in which activities assume binary values representing whether they require a doctor:

```
d = {'activity': ['Check-up', 'Assessment', 'Medication', 'Medication', 'Medication'], 'doctor_requirement': [1, 0,0,0,0]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df
    activity    doctor_requirement
0   Check-up    1
1   Assessment  0
2   Medication  0
3   Medication  0
4   Medication  0
```

I would like to consider that a percentage of `'Medication'` activities require a doctor. That is, to assign binary 1 to `doctor_requirement` for a percentage of `'Medication'` visits. For instance, such that 50% of the activity `'Medication'` requires a doctor (i.e. `doctor_requirement = 1`).

I would greatly appreciate your help, I've been looking online and can't seem to find how to apply such a condition.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like a 50% chance then you can use:

```
df.loc[df['activity']=='Medication','doctor_requirement'] = np.random.choice([0,1],(df['activity']=='Medication').sum())
```

If you wish to contorl the probabilities for 0 and 1s, you can use [np.random.choice](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html)'s `p` parameter to specify odds.

```
df.loc[df['activity']=='Medication','doctor_requirement'] = np.random.choice([0,1],(df['activity']=='Medication').sum(),p=[0.99,0.01])
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I was using a very similar code before, but that code calculates a chance for the values of ```Medication``` being 1 or 0 as a whole. For example, the 50% chance above implies that either all values for ```Medication``` are 0 or they are all 1. Instead, I will like that condition to take place for each individual ```activity``` value such that, for instance, a 50% chance will lead two values of 1 and one value of 0 for ```doctor_requirement```. Would you know how to implement that?

Comment: Thank you, I was unaware of this behaviour, please check the edit.